# I have an SSL everywhere site and I'm getting errors pulling content from my azure video streaming service

Tags: ssl, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I'm using SSL in my whole site so I get errors when I pull video streaming content from my azure media services account.  All of the urls I get for origin server streaming content when I publish are http.  I need them to be https.  Is there anyway I can configure the origin service or something I can do before I publish to make the service serve these requests with SSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Windows Azure Media Services (WAMS) doesn't support Https.

The formats for streaming, like HLS, are actually transfer formats like Http. HLS doesn't by nature support HTTPS. Instead it has other content protection mechanisms, WAMS uses HLS + 128-bit AES. All of the content transferred in the stream is encrypted by AES.

Depending on your security requirements, you shouldn't need to serve the requests with https. The request that retrieves the origin locator url should be https already, the request that stores it in your database should be https, the request that provides the url to a client should be https, so with the default AES encryption it's entirely secure.

Comment: So how do I go about getting my green lock for ssl security back if I'm pulling from urls that don't have https on them?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue with browser showing mixed content?